# Like a Page, Newsletter Opt-In and Questions

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-page

first time Facebook developer so was hoping for some guidance. Been given a very brief spec:

> Requirement is to run it where fans have to give email (so that we can
>   contact winners) with opt in for newsletter sign up and also must FB
>   like VF to be entered into prize draw. There will be options to choose
>   from. They choose one and can't vote more than once.

So I'm thinking about a Facebook application that sits as a tab on the facebook page. If the user hasn't "Liked" the page, they'll be encouraged to "Like" the page in order to proceed.

If it's liked, they'll have an option to opt into our newsletter. They will also be allowed to answer one question with one answer. When they submit it, they will then be entered into a competition.

If they pick the "right" option, we will send them an email telling them so.

**Right** - does this sound fairly straightforward? Are there any guides, examples or tutorials that could help? Am I going about it in the right way?

Many thanks in advance,

JJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds very straightforward and you are going about it in the right way.

The best tutorials and examples can probably be found in the Facebook Developers documentation and in the example files within the PHP SDK (http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/)

To find out if the current viewing user has liked the page or not check out the signed request that Facebook passes to your app tab. It contains this and a lot more useful information http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty much how the majority of companies are pushing forward with Facebook.  They are driving up the `Like` count by forcing users to `Like` the page before getting to their goodies.  There are lots of examples on the internet as to how to create a page which checks if the user likes the page.  As you've not stated what programming language you are going to be tackling this in, it is going to be hard to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm open to any languages at this moment in time. As I am a bit behind, I was looking at FBML but soon realised that they are deprecating it.

Comment: Don't start a new project with FBML. Use an iframe instead.

Comment: Cool - after digging around "properly" I've also come to this conclusion!

Comment: @Charles Dowd: FBML pages are no longer available.